# Non portale pointer conversion

Tags: c, arrays, exception, pointers, warnings

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void change(int *);
int main()
{
 int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
 int i;
 clrscr();
 change(a);
 for(i=4;i>=0;i--)
    {
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
 getch();
 return 0;
}
void change(int *b)
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
 {
  b=*b+1; //showing nonportable pointer exception
  b++;
 }
}
```

The output is not as expected, no error and 1 warning....
Expected Output: 65432
Current Output: 54321

Comment: Perhaps if you actually **read** and **tried to fix** the warning... `b = *b + 1` should've been `*b = *b + 1` or simply `*b += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is of type `int *` while `*b + 1` is of type `int`. You are assigning `int` type to pointer type. Change

```
 b=*b+1;
```

to

```
*b = *b+1;
```

Comment: I have a feeling that people won't ever learn that warnings should be treated as hard errors...